# GIMP command line, how to invert color of a list of picture and modify the color of them (by colorize, but in command line)

Tags: linux, terminal, gimp

I'm trying to modify a list of images with the terminal, I want to invert the color and apply a color with colorize, all of this with the command gimp and in the terminal.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

You're going to have an easier time doing this with something like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) than GIMP on the command line.

With ImageMagick, you can use the [negate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#negate) command:

```
convert image.jpg -negate negated-image.jpg
```

And then [colorize](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorize) it:

```
convert negated-image.jpg -colorize 0,50,0 colorized-image.jpg
```